# Android TabLayout - replacement fragment in tab

Tags: android

This should be simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

I am setting up TabLayout with setupViewViewPager such that I have 3 tabs (Home, Tab1, Tab2). How do I set it so that when I click on a link in Tab1, a new fragment replaces the existing fragment?

Answer (score 1):

**Your XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabPaddingStart="20dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Your java code**

```
public class ClassName extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xml_file_name);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setupViewPager();
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentName1(),"Home");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentName2(),"Tab1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentName3(),"Tab2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I solved my problem by creating a fragment for each tab, each containing a unique FrameLayout.

Next, I used my activity to add a fragment to the FrameLayout (depending on which tab is selected) with FragmentTransaction.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it did work for me.

Comment: would you be able to show your code to do this? do you need to create a fragment as well as fragment.xml for each tab? plus the original fragments that were going to be used in the tabs